# NormalizedDifference gives value of 0

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1

I'm working with sentinel -1 image and i'm trying to compute NRPB equation as mention here:
[image]

I have applied Frost filter and then I tried to applly this normalized difference on one image only but for some reason the values I get is 0.

This is how I have tried to calculte the normalized difference:

```
var nrbp=imgFrost.normalizedDifference(['VH_sum','VV_sum']).rename('NRPB');
print(nrbp);
Map.addLayer(nrbp,{},'NRBP');
```

and this is link for the full code with geometry:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/3eb828ed8320154560d92a62e3d53755

My end goal: to calculte the differences and get real values instead of 0

Edit:
For some reason when I write it like this it works:

```
var VH = imgFrost.select('VH_sum');
var VV = imgFrost.select('VV_sum');
var nrbp = VH.subtract(VV).divide(VH.add(VV)).rename('NRBP');
Map.addLayer(nrbp,{},'NRBP');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs, my highlight:

> normalizedDifference(bandNames)
>
> Computes the normalized difference between two bands. If the bands to
>   use are not specified, uses the first two bands. The normalized
>   difference is computed as (first − second) / (first + second). **Note
>   that negative input values are forced to 0** so that the result is
>   confined to the range (-1, 1).

So, in your case you're probably better off calculating it yourself.